# why doesnt i get the variable?

Tags: javascript, json

im trying to let a variable from JSON and use it in other function but I'm doing something wrong can someone help me?
the code is`

```
async function githubUsers() {
  let response = await fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/b9f7261a-3444-4bb7-9706-84b1b521107d')
  let shipsJSON =  await response.json()
}

githubUsers()



shipsJSON.forEach((item) => {
  item.forEach((nestedItem) => {
    placeCharacter(nestedItem.x, nestedItem.y, "O", myGrid)
    // placeCharacter(nestedItem.x, nestedItem.y, 'O', myGrid);
    placeRandomCharacter('O', enemyGrid, enemyGridSize);
    drawBreak();

  })
```

Comment: Because that variable is created in function scope
https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/2930038

Answer (score -1):

Because `shipsJSON` is scoped to the githubUsers function. Maybe the best way is to `await` that returned data within another `async` function, and then loop over the data.

```js
async function githubUsers() {
  let response = await fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/b9f7261a-3444-4bb7-9706-84b1b521107d');
  return response.json();
}

async function main() {
  const shipsJSON = await githubUsers();
  // rest of your code
}

main();
```

Alternatively since `fetch` returns a promise:

```js
function githubUsers() {
  return fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/b9f7261a-3444-4bb7-9706-84b1b521107d');
}

async function main() {
  const response = await githubUsers();
  const shipsJSON = await response.json();
  // rest of your code
}

main();
```

Comment: There's no need to make gitHubUsers async — since fetch returns already a Promise. In your example an async `main` is quite enough.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. I was following the OP's code. Seems like they wanted to separate things out.

Comment: So all you've done is replace `async/await` with a promise/then. How is that an improvement?

Answer (score -2):

You are using async function, so `githubUsers` call won't complete before your foreach loop. Also, you are declaring `shipsJSON` variable inside scope of `githubUsers`, meaning it won't be available outside it. So you should use `return` to get it to outer scope. Do it like this:

```js
async function githubUsers() {
  let response = await fetch('https://run.mocky.io/v3/b9f7261a-3444-4bb7-9706-84b1b521107d')
  return response.json()
}

async function fetchAndLoop() {
    const json = await githubUsers()



    json.forEach((item) => {
      item.forEach((nestedItem) => {
        placeCharacter(nestedItem.x, nestedItem.y, "O", myGrid)
        // placeCharacter(nestedItem.x, nestedItem.y, 'O', myGrid);
        placeRandomCharacter('O', enemyGrid, enemyGridSize);
        drawBreak();

      });
}

fetchAndLoop();
```